# Using WebRequest to communicate with php using C#

Tags: c#, php, api, xamarin.android, webrequest

it is for a Xamarin android project, I want to make it as simplest as possible so I follow a tutorial on how inserting data into a mysql database using webrequest and php.

Here is my Activity where I retrieve the input through editTexts

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace CPDEP1
{
    [Activity(Label = "Formulaire d'enregistrement", Theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light")]
    public class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        CoordinatorLayout FrootLayout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FrootLayout = FindViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(Resource.Id.FcoordLayout);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Form);
            var inputNom = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nom);
            var inputPrenom = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.pren);
            var inputTel = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tel);
            var inputID = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.iden);
            var inputDep = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.dep);
            var inputCom = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.com);
            var savebtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.save);
            var inputAdresse = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.adresse);
            var inputCourriel = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.email);

            savebtn.Click += delegate
            {
                string nom = inputNom.Text;
                string prenom = inputPrenom.Text;
                string tel = inputTel.Text;
                string id = inputID.Text;
                string dep = inputDep.Text;
                string com = inputCom.Text;
                string adress = inputAdresse.Text;
                string courriel = inputCourriel.Text;

                //REceiving value from an activity
                //string user = Intent.GetStringExtra("User");
                //string pass = Intent.GetStringExtra("Password");


                if (nom == null || prenom == null || tel == null || id == null || dep == null || com == null || adress == null || courriel == null)
                {
                    ////////////SSNACKBAR///////////
                    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.Make(FrootLayout, "Empty Field", Snackbar.LengthShort)
                                             .SetAction("", (view) =>
                                             {
                                                 Toast.MakeText(this, "OK", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                                             }).SetActionTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));

                    View SnackView = snack.View;
                    SnackView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#E72222"));
                    snack.Show();

                }
                else
                {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/CRUDSERVICE/CreateContact.php");
                    NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

                    parameters.Add("Nom", nom);
                    parameters.Add("Prenom", prenom);
                    parameters.Add("Tel", tel);
                    parameters.Add("Dep", dep);
                    parameters.Add("Com", com);
                    parameters.Add("Adress", adress);
                    parameters.Add("Courriel", courriel);

                    client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);





                }
            };

    }

    //  }


}
```

}

And the PHP scripts 
one for the connexion

```
<?php

class ConnectionInfo
{
    public $mServerName;
    public $mConnectionInfo;
    public $conn;

    public function GetConnection()
    {
        $this->mServerName = 'localhost';
        $this->mConnectionInfo = array("Database"=>"formation", "UID"=>"root", "PWD"=>"cpdep");
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->mServerName,$this->mConnectionInfo);

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

the other for CRUD

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php');


if (isset($_POST['Nom']) && isset($_POST['Prenom']) && isset($_POST['Tel']) && isset($_POST['Dep']) && isset($_POST['Com']) && isset($_POST['Adress']) && isset($_POST['Courriel']))
{
    //Get the POST variables
    $mNom = $_POST['Nom'];
    $mPrenom = $_POST['Prenom'];
    $mTel = $_POST['Tel'];
    $mDep = $_POST['Dep'];
    $mCom = $_POST['Com'];
    $mAdress = $_POST['Adress'];
    $mCourriel = $_POST['Courriel'];


    //Set up our connection
    $connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    $connectionInfo->GetConnection();

    if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
    {
        //Connection failed
        echo 'No Connection';
    }

    else
    {
        //Insert new contact into database
        $query = 'INSERT INTO thinktank (nom, prenom, telephone, departement, commune, adresse, courriel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $parameters = array($mNom, $mPrenom, $mTel, $mDep, $mCom, $mAdress, $mCourriel);

        //Execute query
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query, $parameters);

        if (!$stmt)
        {   //The query failed
            echo 'Query Failed';    
        }

        else
        {
            //The query succeeded, now echo back the new contact ID
            $query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Contacts') AS NewID";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo $row['NewID']; 
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have triedueverything for the past 3 hours. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly is your issue, you have two server side languages.  If either formulates a valid web request, the other should be able to accept it.

Comment: That's the problem I don't know where I mess up, I am only sure my php script got no error , I am not familiar with WebRequest yet , I am not certain if I correctly use it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to change your php from `POST` to `GET`

Just replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`

After that, if you want to call your URL just do like this example

```
http://localhost/CRUDSERVICE/CreateContact.php?Nom=Doe&Prenom=Joe&Tel=025545&Dep=Security&Com=somecom&Adress=street431&Courriel=youremail@gmail.com


String prenom="john";
String nom="doe";
String tel="025545";
String dep="security";
String com="somecom";
String adress="street431";
String courriel="youremail@gmail.com";
// let's build our link
String link="http://localhost/CRUDSERVICE/CreateContact.php?Nom="+nom+"&Prenom="+prenom+"&Tel="+tel+"&Dep="+dep+"&Com="+com+"&Adress+"+adress+"&Courriel="+courriel;
WebClient wc=new WebClient(); // don't forget using System.Net;
String res=wc.DownloadString(link); // res is data printed by echo
if(res.equals("No Connection ") || res.equals("Query Failed"))
{
  // something went wrong
}
else
{

}
```